# How Count Time In Session Login

Tags: php, session

I know many who have asked about the login session. But until now I have not found information that was so obvious.

Session I have code like this

```
session_start();
setcookie(session_name('ksLogin'),session_id(),time()+2*7*24*60*60);
```

It was only active for two weeks only.
I want to modify the session to one year or more, but do not know how to get started.

Which makes me confused here because there are 5 groups and are not explained by the owner of the tutorial.

Could you tell us about the performance of code that session and if there is nothing better than what I wrote above?

I fear there are some types of browsers that do not support this session. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

The code has:

> 2 weeks is 2 x 7 days x 24 hours x 60 mins x 60 seconds:

```
setcookie(session_name('ksLogin'),session_id(),time()+2*7*24*60*60);
```

So change it to:

> 1 year = 365 days x 24 hours x 60 mins x 60 seconds:

```
setcookie(session_name('ksLogin'),session_id(),time()+365*24*60*60);
```

Comment: It does not work and disappear once the browser session is closed

Comment: @Kangsigit What code doesn't work and what disappears?

Comment: the active period of the session disappears after the browser is closed.

Comment: @Kangsigit Sessions are meant to be like that.

Comment: @Kangsigit What code are you coding using the sessions or cookies. Kindly put that.